# ¿Como quitar el setError de un EditText con contenido de DatePicker despues de que ya se coloco la fecha?

Tags: java, android-studio

Estoy teniendo unos detalles al momento de validar los campos `EditText` principalmente en donde tengo las fechas con `DatePicker`, al momento que selecciono la fecha del calendario y se agrega y me paso al otro campo de fecha pero el icono rojo del error se mantiene ahí no se quita, no detecta que ya esta lleno ese campo el cual se debería de quitar.

**Archivo de la fechas xml**

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:hint="Fecha de ingreso"
            android:textColorHint="@color/blancogris"
            app:boxStrokeColor="@color/teal_200"
           >

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/fecha_ingreso"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:inputType="date"
                android:textSize="18dp" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

   <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:hint="Fecha de caducidad"
            android:textColorHint="@color/blancogris"
            app:boxStrokeColor="@color/teal_200"
            >

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/fecha_caducidad"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:inputType="date"
                android:textSize="18dp" />
      </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayou>
```

**Método de validación**

```
    String fechaRegistro= texfechaingreso.getText().toString().trim();
    String fechaCaducidad= texfechacaducidad.getText().toString().trim();

if (fechaRegistro.isEmpty()){
        texfechaingreso.setError("Favor de llenar el campo fecha de ingreso");
        retorno = false;

    }else{
        texfechaingreso.setError(null);

    }

    if (fechaCaducidad.isEmpty()){
        texfechacaducidad.setError("Favor de llenar el campo fecha de caducidad");
        retorno = false;
    }else{
        texfechacaducidad.setError(null);

    }
```

**Captura de pantalla mostrando los iconos de error aun cuando el campo ya esta lleno con las fechas correspondientes**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Una posible solución es que en vez de preguntar si el `String` está vacío, cuentes los caracteres usando `length`.

```
if(textfechaingreso.getText().toString().length() == 0){ //si la cantidad de caracteres es 0, nos muestra el error
  textfechaingreso.setError("Favor de llenar el campo Fecha de Ingreso.");
 } else {//en caso contrario, no lo mostrará
  textfechaingreso.setError(null);
 }

if(textfechacaducidad.getText().toString().length() == 0){
  textfechacaducidad.setError("Error");
 } else {
  textfechacaducidad.setError(null)
 }
```

Otra cosa es que `isEmpty()` funciona para validar cuando vas a ejecutar una acción, es decir, cuando vas a presionar un botón, es ahí cuando entrará en el `if`.

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario Franqo Balsamo antes yo tenia así pero igual no me funciono esta raro eso, pero ya lo hice las validaciones de otra forma.

Comment: ¿Pudiste solucionar tu problema?

Comment: Si Franqo Balsamo implemente el Toast para la validaciones.